# Locking texbox scrollbar in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, scrollbar

I've got read-only text box with **vertical** scroll bar. Program automatically adds new line text to the text box every 3 seconds. After couple of seconds, scroll bar becomes active and I can scroll it, lets say text box is length enough for 4 lines of text, so after 15 second I can scroll it down.
The problem is, that when I scroll down to the bottom/middle/whatever, after 3 seconds (when loop add new line), scroll bar is reset to the start point. How to lock it, so even if I'm in the middle of the text box and want to read data, the scroll won't get me up?

Ok, so my code looks like this (I removed not needed for this post lines):

```
public void addToBox(Byte b, bool nextRound)

        {
                   if (nextRound)
                    {
                        textBox1.Text += "\r\n";
                    }
                    textBox1.Text += System.Convert.ToString(b) + " ";
         }
```

It converting received `bytes` to `string`.

Comment: Are you doing a post back everytime you add a new line or are you using some javascript ?

Comment: I edited and I think it shows how I add new line. For my case, its every 5 bytes (array of bytes has 5 entries).

Answer (score 0):

Try using (This won't lock the scroll bar but remember where it was before the page load):

```
this.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
```

in your page load for the page. This will resolve the issue if you are adding the new line server side.

Comment: I'm not sure where to put it in. I'm working on a small part of the bigger project. I tried in texbox, but it didn't work.